# Which DATATYPE is better to use TEXT or VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql

This question is based on two things **performance** and **size**

Which DATATYPE is better to use TEXT or VARCHAR? Based on performance which will affect and which will impove?

Comment: _Caution: Many of the Answers and Comments are either out of date, nor never were exactly correct._

Answer (score 110):

**It depends on what you're using it for.** I hate to give such a generic answer, but it's true. Generally, try to get the data type as specific as you can. If your strings will never exceed some upper limit of characters, then go with `VARCHAR` because it will be a little more efficient. If you need more space, go with `TEXT`. If you aren't sure how much space your text will take up, you should probably go with `TEXT`; the performance difference isn't very large, and it's better to be future-proof than risk having to change it later when your requirements change. Just my two cents.

---

In the comments, Pitarou points out that, if MySQL creates a temporary table for your query (see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)), `TEXT` columns will not be stored in memory and will have to be read from the disk, which is much slower. ([Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html), bottom of the page.) This shouldn't matter for most queries, though.

In case anyone was wondering how PostgreSQL compares, I found [this benchmark](http://www.depesz.com/2010/03/02/charx-vs-varcharx-vs-varchar-vs-text/) that shows that CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT all perform equally well. So if you're using Postgres, it doesn't matter what type you use.

Comment: +1 for it depends cause it always does. Just as a side note I've altered columns before from varchar to text and all seems to convert nicely. It seems mysql will try to intelligently convert the data when its datatype changes.

Comment: The MySQL docs state that TEXT can be slower, because the MEMORY storage engine doesn't support this datatype, so you should only use TEXT if you really need it.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html

Comment: @Pitarou: That's only if you're using a query that results in a temporary table, so it won't matter for straightforward queries. Still, good find, that's useful to know.

Comment: I think @noushy has the [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13308666/6384937) for MySQL >= V 5.0.3, as VARCHAR allows a length of up to 64k from that version. Therefore it doesn't have any drawbacks compared to TEXT (which btw. has a fixed upper limit of 64k), while still having potentially better performance.

Comment: i may still re-ask this question bc this one is so old; but happened upon your msg, Bastian. in my case a msSQL2008 Trigger gives this error: “Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.” so we opted to convert our text field to varchar(max) [on dev db]. we are concerned/hope that there is no loss of data or integrity concerns when ported over to prod database. searching for clues to that effect.

Comment: "Large" `VARCHARs` also force MyISAM instead of MEMORY for tmp tables.

Comment: @BastianBlankenburg - but `MEDIUMTEXT` has a limit of 16MB.

Comment: @RickJames the question was about TEXT or VARCHAR not MEDIUMTEXT, so I'd assume that max. 64kb is enough and MEDIUMTEXT is not necessary or relevant here.

Comment: @dcparham my comment was for MySQL (>= V 5.0.3) only, I don't know about msSQL (any version), things might be totally different there.

Answer (score 7):

> From V 5.0.3 onwards, Limit of VARCHAR is increased from 0-256 to 0-65,535 (subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.)
>
> > Ref. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

If you are using TEXT that is fixed 64k length, even if you required lesser limit

So Better to *go with VARCHAR with higher limit* than TEXT.
If requirement is more than 64K go with MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT accordingly.

Comment: Is that true, fixed 64k length? Wasn't it that the data was stored on disk like seperate text files?

Comment: @SimonBaars - Not fixed 64k.  Not separate files; separate blocks, and not always.

Answer (score 7):

> Queries against the TEXT table were always 3 times slower than those against the VARCHAR table (averages: 0.10 seconds for the VARCHAR table, 0.29 seconds for the TEXT table). The difference is 100% repeatable.

Benchmark from http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964

Comment: The benchmark is bogus -- The `TEXT` version uses a prefix index in the `PRIMARY KEY`.  But the `VARCHAR` version does not have that.

Answer (score 2):

VARCHAR you can set a limit for how many chars it will accept per record, text is (virtually) unlimited... not exactly sure about performance, but i would assume a more specific datatype (varchar) would be faster.

Comment: 65535 bytes is not "virtual" limit.

Answer (score 2):

VARCHAR should have a better performance since it has a limited size. In fact, in all of my experiences with MySQL, the search operation was always faster with VARCHAR than TEXT. Anyway, it's based on my experience. You should check the documentation to find out more about it.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your data type.

If your field is fixed-length (e.g. a 32-character hash value), then use CHAR. This has better performance because every entry takes up the same space per row.

The standard limit for VARCHAR was 255 characters but I think it's been increased now. TEXT is pretty damn long and is generally only used for big content like a whole blog post, and comments if you don't want a limit.

With regard to size there is no (or very little) difference between VARCHAR and TEXT since they just store what they need to. CHAR fields will always take up their allotted length.

Performance-wise, VARCHAR is usually faster. VARCHARs can be indexed too which leads to faster searching.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will internally convert TEXT to varchar while creating temporary tables. So it is better to use VARCHAR if possible. There are a few minor bugs related to TEXT column such as...

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36676

Comment: Not always the better solution ! http://nicj.net/mysql-text-vs-varchar-performance/

Answer (score 2):

As per my Opinion VARCHAR is best option when u know the length of characters. It will also reduce garbage Memory Allocations and space issue. TEXT will consume 255 where as VARCHAR will consume as u give the values to it.

As per performance, VARCHAR is also faster then TEXT.

Answer (score -4):

There is a subtle difference in text and varchar. I have a table as shown:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`tbl`(
  `kee` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txt` TEXT(100),
  `vrchr` VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`kee`)
);
```

I insert a row:

```
 INSERT INTO `tbl`
            (`txt`,
             `vrchr`)
VALUES ('1        
         2
         3',
        '1
         2
         3');
```

The column **txt** has value:
*1 

2  

3* 
and column **vrchr** has value: 
*1*

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a DBMS?

Comment: Not sure why you got hammered so badly on this.  It is important for people who store strings that contain newlines for printing to help debug missing characters.