# How can I set maximum character length in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql database, i want to use the varchar field with no limit.  i.e i want to use the varchar field for any number of characters, how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `text` type. It is effectively unlimited. eg

```
create table mytable (
    mycol text
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `varchar` field specifically is not meant for unlimited length if you can fit your data within 255 characters do that otherwise you can use the `text` field instead.

Read more about this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203710/which-datatype-is-better-to-use-text-or-varchar)

Answer (score 0):

use Text instead of Varchar. [check it here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)