# How to Save an SQL query into a table?

Tags: mysql

I am saving an `SQL query` in a database table, so saving the criteria to be used no matter if more records are inputted into the db.

Is there a correct datatype and syntax to use to store the Query statement.
I have set the datatype as `VARCHAR(1055)` as I think that will be enough.
Is there a `MySQL function` that will make sure the text is saved correctly 
in terms of, quotations and keeping it a single string.

Update: Reason for saving query

We allow the users of the system to create a list of contact details based on other users of the system, so they create the query using a form to select say all users with job type of executive.

The above query is then saved in the database, so that even if a new user is added in the executive job type, his contact details will be included when sending communications.

I think this is the best way to do it...do you have any ideas?

Comment: Where are you saving it from?  Directly from the console? From PHP? From PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: A SQL query by itself is just a string, so `varchar` seems like the correct data type to me.  It's very unusual to save a query, though.  I imagine there's a better way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to accomplish.  It also seems like you're creating additional potential SQL injection points in your application, so you'll want to make sure statements are properly sanitized.

Comment: From PHP, check updated reason for query

Comment: I suppose your users are not building the query themselves, but you generate that query based on the options they chose from your form? Then it's enough to save those options - if you can build the query from those once, you can do it again.

Comment: but it's easier to store just the query, provided there are no security flaws

Comment: Maybe it's too late for me to answer. You can try convert it to base64 first before storing it. In this way, you can minimalize the potential of SQL injection.

Comment: Wow looking back on this question - it is so bad. In my opinion I should never have asked the question, I should have looked at what I was doing and tried to figure out an easier less hacky way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VARCHAR(1055)` will never be enough. Just use [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html), MySQL's data type for arbitrary-length text (also called `CLOB` in other databases).

More background info:

- [Which DATATYPE is better to use TEXT or VARCHAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1203710/521799)

Nonetheless, I think you should probably model your query in one way or another on the application layer, instead of storing plain text SQL in your database. When you change your schema, all of those SQL statements might be wrong. Good luck migrating, then!

Another drawback of your approach is that you're creating a big security issue, if users are allowed to enter arbitrary SQL. A nifty intern whose contract wasn't prolonged might store

```
DROP DATABASE my_database.
```

Comment: Well I think I've protected against that by not allowing direct SQl entry and I never post the query, it's stored in session variables and is generated by the system.

Comment: @StephenH: Just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct data type to store a query.

But you can always strip HTML chars by using HTMLencode chars.

Or you can use the PHP `htmlentities()` to convert the characters

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to pass in parameters you could execute a `CREATE VIEW`.  You could just execute the code from PHP using MySQLi.

```
CREATE VIEW myquery AS
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

Usage:

```
SELECT * FROM myquery
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not the right approach. You should not store the resulting query in your database, but instead you should store the parameters that resulted in that created sql. In your implementation when you want to change that query, you'd have to parse your stored SQL to get parameters in order to display your filter form to user. However if you keep your parameters instead, you always can regenerate the query when needed, and easily can display current filter form.

If you do insist of storing your SQL tho, as noted before me, TEXT is the correct field type, as it is much less likely to cut off your sql string at field size limit.