# Getting garbage value while inserting data in MySql longtext field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working in an application in php codeigniter framework and back-end as MySql. In my database there is a table called `blog` in which there is a field called `blog_data` which is `longtext` type Collation `latin1_swedish_ci` Null `No` Default `None`.

When I insert data with # tag like

> 'We salute ‪#‎blooddonors on ‪#‎worldbloolding for ‪#‎blooddonation
>   and saving lives'

It insert some garbage value in the blog_data field and shows like

> 'We salute ?#?blooddonors on ?#?worldblooldingfor
>   ?#?blooddonation
> and saving lives'

I tried to change the Collation but doesn't work for me. i am not getting why it is taking garbage value. I am also not getting the problem is from MySql table structure or from the Codeigniter insert operation.

for inserting data I am writing following code in Model part of codeigniter

```
$data = array(               
                'blog_data' => $this->input->post('blog_content')
            );
            $this->db->insert('blog', $data);
            $this->db->trans_complete();
```

Please guide for following issue. that how can I restrict from inserting garbage value.

Comment: You really need to change your DB collation to utf8_bin **and** the collation of tables as well. Also, you may want to output the value of `blog_content` in order to really be sure the data you're inserting is the real deal.

Comment: Thankyou Linesofcode changing Collation to utf8_bin has worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be content editor issue - do You use any? - f.e. Tinymce. It has automatic escaping, but you can disable this on init.

Also do you set_value function inside textarea? If yes set, the third parameter to false : `set_value('field','defalut_value', FALSE);`

$this->input->post('') doesn't escape by default.

Ah, and try to stick with utf8 in your db.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in `config/database.php`

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

and in `config/config.php`

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

> and better to use `varchar` for data filed.  [Which DATATYPE is better to use TEXT or VARCHAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203710/which-datatype-is-better-to-use-text-or-varchar)

Comment: Thankyou Abdulla but i am already using the same. i have another field with varchar there same problem is coming

Comment: check ur database collation and filed name is UTF-8 in mysql