# Store big string without affecting performance

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a Social Media app where users can post things. It is then stored in a MySQL database and the content is stored using VarChar.

My problem is VarChars max character length is 535 characters. I was planning to make the max a user can type to be around 400 or so the problem is emojis can take up 5-10 characters since they are converted to unicode.

Should I be using something such as MediumBlob or MediumText the tooltip says it stores with three-byte so would this use more storage or what does this mean? And will these affect performance such as the MySQL query time or anything?

Comment: Check this post, it might be helpful. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203710/which-datatype-is-better-to-use-text-or-varchar][1]

Comment: No, the `TEXT` types are still of variable length and will not waste storage space, but are limited in maximum size.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I never noticed TEXT always thought it was also 535. But I think that will work.

Comment: @Dan http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1752305&seqNum=2 seems like a decent write up. Good luck.

Comment: "varChars max character length is 535 characters" no its not

Comment: @smith That's what the tooltip says?

Comment: what "tool tip"? what every software you are using is simply wrong, you should check the manual. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html "Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535. " ...

Comment: @smith I use PhpMyAdmin

Comment: I have never seen it say that, so no idea, but that's not the point. get use to reading manuals, the official sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `TEXT` which I always thought was the same was `VARCHAR`